# How can i remove object after calling his method?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am doing a pc game. What I need is: after object Bomb make his attack I want to remove her from my `ArrayList<Entity>`.

`Entity` is my abstract class for all enemies, like bomb, archer...  I use `ArrayList` to indicate what I need to draw and update. If it's possible, I want to remove that object at all, not just from `ArrayList`.

Here is my code of GameEngine class:

```
    public class GameEngine {
      gameEntities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
      Bomb bomb1;

      bomb1 = new Bomb();
      gameEntities.add(bomb1)
      public void update() {   
        for(Entity entity : gameEntities){
            entity.whatNow();
        }        
      }
    }
```

And other classes:

```
    public class Bomb extends Entity { 
      void whatNow() {
        GameData.entityRemove(this);
      }
    }

    public class GameData {
      static void entityRemove(Entity entity) {
        for(Entity listEntity : GameEngine.gameEntities){
            if(entity == listEntity){
                 listEntity = null;
                 GameEngine.gameEntities.remove(listEntity);
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: Why not use a map instead of a list?

Comment: `GameData.entityRemove(this)` looks completely useless to me, can't you just call `GameEngine.gameEntities.remove(this)` directly?

Comment: Anyway, you can't let bombs remove themself from that list. If you do you will break the gameEngine update loop. You should let the bombs mark themself as "toClean" and let the gameEngine remove them after the `whatNow()` updates. I would implement this self-marking in the `Entity` class

Comment: I found something like "Object exit as long as application know, what he is. Thats why object cant remove itself. Thats why I tried use another class.

Comment: Thanks for advances, will try it after arriving to another café. Thanks a lot Oneiros.

Comment: You're welcome jakub! I wrote an answer, accept it if you like it :) happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let the bombs mark themself as "toClean" and let the `GameEngine` remove them after the `whatNow()` updates (I assume that your `GameEngine` is a singleton):

```
public class Bomb extends Entity { 
  void whatNow() {
    // do my bomb stuff
    GameEngine.instance().remove(this);
  }
}

public class GameEngine {

  // Declare a gameEntitiesToRemove queue/list

  public void update() {
    for(Entity entity : gameEntities){
       entity.whatNow();
    }
    while(gameEntitiesToRemove.hasNext()){
       gameEntities.remove(gameEntitiesToRemove.pop());
    }
  }

  public void remove(Entity entity) {
    this.gameEntitiesToRemove.add(entity);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Entity` in your context shouldn't directly access elements of the `GameEngine`. I would rather suggest something like this:

- your engine has **two** lists: one for `current` things, and one for `future` things
- your code simply walks trough the `current` list
- when processing an entry leads to a `future` event, one should call a method such as `addFuture(Entity whatever)` on the master `GameEngine` object
- when you are dong processing the `current` list - then you clear `current` and **move** all entries from `future` into it
- then you clear `future` and start processing `current` again

In other words: avoid removing entries. Simply process a list once, throw it away and collect "new" entries within a second list.

And unrelated: read about the @Override annotation and start using it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the if-clause inside the for-loop:

```
listEntity = null;
GameEngine.gameEntities.remove(listEntity);
```

The second line would remove the listEntity from the ArrayList, if listEntity would not be set to null in the first line. Now it tries to remove null from the list, which is likely not what you want.

At the very least, swap these two lines. However there is really no point in setting *listEntity* to null, as a local variable it will be gone after that loop anyway.